# How to keep from losing Normal.dotm?

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-backup, templates

Twice recently, my computer crashed while I had Word open. When restarting, it said something like "Do you want to reload Normal.dotm?".  I said "OK" but was then told something like "Could not load normal.dotm". Then it loaded a fresh new copy of Normal.dotm, totally devoid of my customized styles and macro code.

Even though I had AutoSave active in my documents, I had manually clicked "Save" at some point yesterday. And I had also clicked "Save" in the VBA editor window. But these steps didn't prevent the template from going away nor did they create a backup version.

- Why isn't the template being backed up?
- Is there a setting to do that?
- I can start keeping macros in a different global template so they're save if Normal is lost, but is there a similar way to save styles?

Comment: Are you referring to the Modify Styles box where it says "New documents based on this template"? Because I think (in my case) that's Normal.dotm.  Also, I have a lot of legacy documents whose styles I need to update, and having everything in one template will make that much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You are not obliged to use Normal.dotm as your template, as Word tends
to recreate this file whenever it becomes corrupted.

You may use your own template, with any file-name.

- Menu *File > Save As*
- Type a name for the template
  and the Type as "Word Template"
- Click Save.
  The file is automatically stored in the "Custom Office Templates" folder

To start a new file based on your template, click
*File > New > Custom* and click your template.

This way your template will stay safely out of the way.

Reference :
[Create a template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb).

Answer (score 0):

### There may well be a backup. If not here is how to back up using a macro.

First, look in your [User Templates Folder](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#UserTemplates) for a file named "Backup of Normal.wbk." If it is there, delete the new Normal.dotm if present and rename the backup Normal.dotm. Here is [my page on how to find that folder](https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Find).

The Normal template is the repository of a lot of user customization and seems to be a target for all sorts of problems. I run a macro to create a backup every once in a while. Here is [my article on the Microsoft site discussing this in depth](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/backup-normaldotm-template-using-a-macro/81aea1ae-e31b-437e-ac4a-3ebf9b4f7b5f).

> The macro, as written:
>
> - Puts the backups in a separate folder from the normal template. That folder will be named "Normal Backups" and will be located in the
>   same folder as your user templates folder. By default, this folder is
>   located in:
>   `C:\Users\ user name \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`
>   but this can be different, depending on your operating system and on
>   your own user settings. See: [How to Find the Normal Template](https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Find)
> - If your computer uses the default, the backups folder will be:
>   `C:\Users\ user name \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Normal Backups`
> - Creates the backups folder if it does not already exist
> - When run, saves the normal template directly. This line can be eliminated if you want. It increases how long it takes the macro to
>   run.
> - Creates a new backup of the normal template with a date and time stamp in the name. This will not appear in the Recent Files lists.

**Here is the Windows version macro:**

> ```
> Sub NormalBackup()
>  ' Run to Backup Normal template to dated backup
>  ' Charles Kenyon 10 Jan 2020 
>  '  https://www.addbalance.com/word/normal-backup.htm
>  ' Appends date to "Normal Backup" when saving, saves in special folder, 
>  '   then returns save path to current - thanks to Jay Freedman for that
>  ' This code must be in the Normal template to work - not in another global
>
>  '
>  On Error Resume Next
>  Dim strName As String
>  Dim intLenPath As Integer ' length of path to templates folder without name of folder
>  Dim strPath As String 'Holder for current path
>  Dim strStorePath As String
>  '
>  Let intLenPath = InStrRev(Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath), _
>     "\")
>  Let strStorePath = Left(Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath), _
>     intLenPath)
>  Let strStorePath = strStorePath & "Normal Backups"
>  '
>  ' Check if folder exists, if not, create it
>  If Dir(strStorePath) = vbNullString Then MkDir (strStorePath)
>  '
>  Let strPath = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath)
>  Let strName = "Normal Backup"
>  ' add date & Time
>  Let strName = strName & " " & Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & "-" & _
>     Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "-" & _
>     Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") & "-" & _
>     Format(Now(), "HH_mm") 'add date & time
>  '
>  ' Do the save
>  ' MsgBox strStorePath & strName & ".dotm"
>  ThisDocument.Save 'save normal template (code holder) itself
>  ThisDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strStorePath & "\" & strName & ".dotm", Addtorecentfiles:=False
>  ' Reset save path
>  Let Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) = strPath
>  '
>  ' reset error message
>  On Error GoTo -1
>  End Sub
> ```

*All of the links above are to pages I have written and control. The two below are to those written by respected Word gurus.*

> **What to do with the Macro**
>
> See:
>
> - [Instructions for Installing Macros from Forums or Websites](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by Graham Mayor, MVP
> - [Install/Employ VBA Procedures (Macros)](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html) by Greg Maxey, MVP
>
> You are going to want to place the macro in your normal template. It
> can be in a separate module.
>
> The name of the Macro is "NormalBackup."
>
> If you display the list of macros from within Word, you can find it
> there in alphabetical order. **Alt+F8** will display a list of macros. (It
> may be **Fn+Alt+F8**. *On the Mac it is **Opt** instead of **Alt**.*)